# Why Ansible skip items in inserafter?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have about 10 hosts that I run a playbook for them with `serial:1`. in this playbook there is this code which append output of all commands in one file:

```
    - name: copy the output to a local file
      lineinfile:
       dest: "{{ myshell_output4.stdout }}"
       line: "{{ item }}"
       insertafter: EOF
      with_items:
        - "########################################################"
        - "###############HOSTNAME:{{ inventory_hostname }}################"
        - "{{ myshell_output3.stdout }}"
        - "########################END#############################"
     delegate_to: localhost
```

it is always working for the first host but for others it only insert second and third line and skip first and last line. the out put of file is like this:

```
  ########################################################
  ###############HOSTNAME:12.15.1.1################
  (some output here)
  ########################END#############################
  ###############HOSTNAME:12.15.2.2################
  (some output here)
  ###############HOSTNAME:12.15.3.3################
  (some output here)
  .
  .
```

why this happen and how i can prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `delegate_to` and `lininfile` or `blockinfile` do not work properly together, https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28313.

### Module `blockinfile`

It seems redundant lines have not been written as you would expect. Eventually, `blockinfile` without a marker does the job.

```
- name: copy the output to a local file
  blockinfile:
    dest: "{{ myshell_output4.stdout }}"
    marker: false
    block: |
      ########################################################
      ###############HOSTNAME:{{ inventory_hostname }}################
      {{ myshell_output3.stdout }}
      ########################END#############################
  delegate_to: localhost
```

### Concatenate files at the end

Alternatively, you can write to different files and concatenate those files after all tasks have run.

```
- name: copy the output to a local file
  copy:
    content: |
      ########################################################
      ###############HOSTNAME:{{ inventory_hostname }}################
      {{ myshell_output3.stdout }}
      ########################END#############################
    dest: tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: log files are concatenated
  assemble:
    src: tmp/
    dest: "{{ myshell_output4.stdout }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true

- name: tmp folder is absent
  path:
    src: tmp/
    state: absent
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

In case your local file `myshell_output4.stdout` does exist already and you want to append to an  existing file, you assemble the files `tmp/*` into `tmp/assembled` and the append them with `lineinfile`.

```
- name: append assembled to a local file
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ myshell_output4.stdout }}"
    line: "{{ lookup('file', tmp/assembled) }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```